# Error: unlockFocus called too many time

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am a relative newbie to cocoa and am building a Mac OS X application. My application (SDK 10.8 + Deployment 10.6) is working perfectly on OSX 10.8 (in fact multiple machines) but on an older 10.6, it crashes. After checking the logs via Instruments, I'm getting the following error:

"unlockFocus called too many time"

After a couple of runs, I've figured that its because of some cocoa drawings I make. I have no idea why this is the case. Is this because of hardware or OS limitations? I've read the Apple documentation but haven't found anything.

I know every situation is different but is there a general reason for this? What does "too many time" really mean? A limit in a certain time?

Comment: You'll need to post your drawing code, or perhaps create a test project that demonstrates the issue (then you can pass that to Apple's Developer Support at least).

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and I solved it by removing a call to `[[NSColor blackColor] redComponent]` (some `NSColor` instances do not support this property).

Comment: When you want to make the drawing appear on the image instead of on the screen, you must first lock focus on the image. When the drawing is complete, you must unlock focus. So might be in your code unlock focus api is being called multiple times. Please check

Comment: It not necessarily related to the problem. Maybe when I drew inside a cell and called redComponent (no need to call {lock|unlock}Focus then), an exception was raised and probably unbalanced the lockFocus/unlockFocus in a higher scope.